# Allocate memory in C#

Tags: c#, c++

I want to convert the code from C++ to C#, there is one line code regarding with `memcpy`. Not sure how to convert it.

```
memcpy(Bucket, nBucket, 4 * L);
```

The original code is from [TopCoderForums.](http://apps.topcoder.com/forums/?module=RevisionHistory&messageID=1038963) I finished most of them except a few lines.

Comment: You use `new` to create new object instances in c#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that specific example of code (where Bucket and nBucket are int arrays) here is what you can do in c#:

```
Array.Copy(nBucket, Bucket, 4 * L)
```

(Note that I think souce and destination should be swapped around)